# How can I improve this DB query? it takes too much time

Tags: mysql, timestamp

The query is this:

```
$today = $date->getTimestamp();

SELECT t.*, u.screen_name, u.profile_image_url
  FROM table AS t 
  LEFT JOIN users AS u 
  ON t.user_id=u.id_str 
  WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.created_at) > {$today}
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 12;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though you didn't post table definitions in your question so I can't tell for sure what is missed, the following indexes will be beneficial  :

1. Index on table (user_id, created_at)
2. Index on users(id_str) or even users(id_str,screen_name,profile_image_url)
3. I guess you already have an index on table(id)

**UPDATE**

Change `WHERE` :
from `WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.created_at) > {$today}`  to `WHERE t.created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME({$today})`, this way optimizer will use index that includes `create_at` column more efficiently.

Comment: yes, I laread have an index to table(id), I'll add these index, that are clever indeed, I addition I was wwondering if the query is a good query itself (with the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.created_at) > {$today} and everything).
Thank I'll add this indexes.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`; mysql doesn't support function based indexes, so I'd recommend to compare `t.created_at` with datetime (avoiding `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function) or change type of `t.created_at`.

Comment: It is faster now that I have added those indexes, but in adition I see I can query like this:
    SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE created_at > '2012-11-20 00:00:00'
So it would be the same as using UNIX_TIMESTAMP()... right?

Comment: @Mariano Argañaraz : Problem with function in mysql that it doesn't use index:  `WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field) > some_value` -- doesn't use index on `field` (it may use index scan in case of covering index, but not index seek or index range scan );  `WHERE field > some_value` does use index on `field` properly... Some other RDMS(Oracle for instance) let you create function based index , but not mysql

Comment: @Mariano Argañaraz: If you change the ` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.created_at) > {$today}`  to ` WHERE field > FROM_UNIXTIME({$today})` the index on `(t.created_at)` will be used properly. I'm updating my answer...

Comment: I recently removed an up-voted and accepted answer of yours. I wanted to make sure you were aware that it was not removed because of any problem with your answer, but rather because the author of the question requested deletion due to sensitive details in the post that would be cumbersome to remove from revision history in other ways.

I feel bad because this had nothing to do with you. I've asked the author of the question to re-post without those details and hopefully you can post the same answer and get the same reward for doing so.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: no worries; I'm not fighting for rank. If the answer was helpful and useful, even negative rating cannot change that fact.

Comment: @a1ex07 that's true, but the answer has been deleted as well, so I just wanted to let you know to watch out for a re-introduced question, because your answer should go back up there if it re-appears.

Comment: @a1ex07 also, I always feel bad when I cost folks rep due to no fault of their own.